# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar un campo específico usando un foreach en codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy teniendo problemas actualizando un campo de una tabla usando codeigniter, el problema es que muestro los datos de las cuentas bancarias inactivas de un usuario, y al dar click en el botón "reactivar" quiero cambiar el Status de 'I' a 'A' (inactivo a activo) sí lo hace pero se actualizan todas las cuentas inactivas, sólo quiero actualizar en la que hago click con el botón. Gracias por su atención.
Esta es la vista:

```
div class='container'>
      <h5>Histórico</h5>
    <table id='table' class='table'>
     <thead>
      <tr>       
        <th>INTERNO</th>
        <th>CLABE</th>
        <th>FECHA_ALTA</th>
        <th>FECHA_BAJA</th>
        <th>STATUS</th>
        <th>ACCIÓN</th>
     </thead>
      <tbody>
<?php
        foreach ($mos-> result() as $row) {
          echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row->Interno;"</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->Clabe;"</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row->Fecha_alta;"</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row->Fecha_baja;"</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row->Status;"</td>"; 
                echo "<td><input type='submit' id='ReActivar' name='ReActivar' class='btn btn-success' value='ReActivar' onclick='return validacion();' disabled><span id='msg'></span></td>";
         "</tr>";  
         }
      ?>    
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Este es el controlador:

```
function decision(){
      if (!empty($_POST['actualizar'])) {
     $this->validaclabe();
      }

    if (!empty($_POST['Desactivar'])) {
   $this->update_Status();
}

if (!empty($_POST['ReActivar'])) {
   $this->update_Status_again();
}
}

function update_Status_again() 
{
     $this->load->helper('date'); 
      date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City'); 
      $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');    
    $Interno = $this->input->post('Interno');
    $Status = $this->input->post('activo');

     $data = array(
     'Status' =>  ! empty($Status) ? $Status : 'A',
    'Fecha_alta' => $now,
  );

    //$data['status'] = ! empty($Status) ? $Status : 'I';
    if ( ! empty($Interno))
    {
        $updated = $this->consultas_M->update_Status($Interno, $data);
        if($updated)
        {
           //echo " update successful...";
           $this->logueado();
           //redirect('index.php/Datos/search2');
        }
        else
        { echo "update not successful...";}  
    } else
    { echo "Interno  not found ..."; }    
}
```

Este es el modelo:

```
function muestra_inactivos($Interno)
     {  $Status = 'A';
        //$Interno = $this->input->get('Interno');
        $this->db->select('Interno, Clabe, Fecha_alta, Fecha_baja, Status');
        $this->db->where('Status !=', $Status);
        $this->db->where('Interno =', $Interno);
    $q= $this->db ->get('cuentas');
  if($q -> num_rows() >= 0){
    return $q;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
  }

 function update_Status_again($Interno,$data)
{
   $this->db->where('Interno', $Interno);
   return $this->db->update('cuentas', $data);
   if ( $this->db->affected_rows() > 0 )
   {
      return TRUE;
   }
   else 
   {
     return FALSE;
   }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Sólo quiero actualizar a 'A' el renglón donde hago click, pero todos los demás se actualizan también.

Comment: si tenes muchos registros de un mismo interno es así como funciona, tendrás que diferenciarlos por un id de registro

Comment: ammm la clabe interbancaria es con b, es algo de mi país

Comment: je si ahi lo vi, pero el resto sigue igual, no estas identificando el registro puntual, necesitas un id, `id_registro`, `id_interno` etc.. traes todos los campos por `id_interno` pero sólo actualizas el  `id_registro` correspondiente

Comment: podrías mostrar la estructura de la tabla cuentas?

Comment: Como dice @alo, al no colocar el identificador de la fila en la que deseas actualizar el valor del estado, te actualiza toda la columna. Tienes que enviar como parámetro el ID de la fila a actualizar desde la vista hacia tu controlador->modelo

Comment: Es que lo que pasa es que es una llave primaria combinada, formada por el interno + la clabe